# Trying to get ViewModel in @Composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Iam trying to learn jetpack compose. Iam stuck with the ViewModels.

I have a ViewModel

```
class DataViewModel: ViewModel() {

    //the list of live data
    var listData = mutableListOf<Data>()

    //initialize the viewmodel
    init {

        viewModelScope.launch {
            //do the network call (this is working ok)
            val data = fetchData()
            data.forEach {
                listData.add(it)
                //print the list of data, this is working fine
                println("listData")
            }

        }
    }
```

So fetching the data and put it in the dataList is working fine. But no i want to display the data on my screen. I made a composable

```
@Composable
//pass in the viewmodel
fun DataScreen(model:DataViewModel = viewModel()){
    println("model.listData")
    this return an empty list ?
    Column{
        model.listData?.forEach { item ->

            Text("${item}")

            }
        }

   }
```

On my screen nothing happens because its an empty list in the composable.
How can i get the list from the ViewModel ?

Comment: set modifier to your column ``Modifier.fillMaxSize()``

Comment: the list iam getting from the viewmodel is empy so that will make no difference i think

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you do not use **State** value in your view model. State is needed in order to register your value for Composable recomposition (in case the value is assigned/changed)

So You need to have View Model like this (I guess your fetchData is a suspend function):

```
   class DataViewModel: ViewModel() {

    //the list of live data
    val listDataState = MutableState<List<Data>> =  mutableStateOf(emptyList<Data>())

    //initialize the viewmodel
    init {

        viewModelScope.launch {
            val data = fetchData()
            listDataState.value = data

        }
    }

    suspend fun fetchData() : List<Data>{
        //something like: 
        return dataRepository.getData()
    }

   }
```

Then in your @Composable function you get the data like this:

```
val viewModel: DataViewModel = viewModel()
val data = viewModel.listDataState.value
```

Comment: tx, this will do the job, its working. Yes the network call is supended. One question. What is the difference in creating the live data list between: MutableState<List<Data>> or MutableLiveData ?

Comment: You can use live data actually, it is just that MutableState is optimized for Jetpack Compose to be used with ease. See this: https://youtu.be/QDcBO4iROyE?t=471

Answer (score 5):

Instead of passing viewModel to fun DataScreen.
you can use below in fun DataScreen -

```
val viewModel = viewModel<DataViewModel>()
```

for this to work add below dependency in app build.gradle -

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.5.1'
```

now you can use viewModel.listData.

Answer (score 1):

***Currently I use this way in my project***

**PokemonDetailScreen.kt**

```
@Composable
fun PokemonDetailScreen(
    dominantColor : Color,
    pokemonName : String,
    navController : NavController,
    topPadding : Dp = 20.dp,
    pokemonImageSize : Dp = 200.dp,
    viewModel : PokemonDetailVm = hiltViewModel()
){

}
```

**PokemonDetailVm.kt**

```
@HiltViewModel
class PokemonDetailVm @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: PokemonRepositoryFeature
): ViewModel(){

    suspend fun getPokemonInfo(pokemonName:String): Resource<Pokemon>{
        return repository.getPokemonInfo(pokemonName)
    }

}
```

**Dependencies**

```
//Dagger - Hilt
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44"
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0-alpha01'
```